# Qt run function with timing in millisecond

Tags: qt, serial-port, timing

I really do not know how to call. It is not really real time but I need this: I have a one embedded solution and I can communicate with it through USART so standard COM port (FTDI). But to start communication, something like authorization proccess I need to keep precise timing. So for examle: power on > wait 10ms > send 0x55 > wait 20ms read the response > ...
I used for this the serialport library for using the COM ports. In 70-80% cases it works fine but you know it is running on Windows and I'm using standard function sleep() from windows library and if the computer has a lot of work it destroy my sequence, because of multitasking. So how can I do that? Can thread help?

Comment: are you trying to get to qt programs to talk over serial?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple sleeper class for you:

```
class Sleeper : public QThread {
public:
    static void msleep(unsigned long v) { QThread::msleep(v); }
};

void sleep(int ms) {
    Sleeper::msleep(ms);
}
```